# UI form validation in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, form-validation, magento2.2, ui-form

I want to validate text field to numeric or not in UI form.

```
<column name="sortorder">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">SortOrder</item>
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Can anyone provide list of validation in UI form in

```
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
</item>
```

Answer (score 38):

**You can use `validate-digits` for validating number**

```
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="validate-digits" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

**Here is the list of validation which you can use in UI form**

```
min_text_length
max_text_length
max-words
min-words
range-words
letters-with-basic-punc
alphanumeric
letters-only
no-whitespace
zip-range
integer
vinUS
dateITA
dateNL
time
time12h
phoneUS
phoneUK
mobileUK
stripped-min-length
email2
url2
credit-card-types
ipv4
ipv6
pattern
validate-no-html-tags
validate-select
validate-no-empty
validate-alphanum-with-spaces
validate-data
validate-street
validate-phoneStrict
validate-phoneLax
validate-fax
validate-email
validate-emailSender
validate-password
validate-admin-password
validate-url
validate-clean-url
validate-xml-identifier
validate-ssn
validate-zip-us
validate-date-au
validate-currency-dollar
validate-not-negative-number
validate-zero-or-greater
validate-greater-than-zero
validate-css-length
validate-number
validate-number-range
validate-digits
validate-digits-range
validate-range
validate-alpha
validate-code
validate-alphanum
validate-date
validate-identifier
validate-zip-international
validate-state
less-than-equals-to
greater-than-equals-to
validate-emails
validate-cc-number
validate-cc-ukss
required-entry
checked
not-negative-amount
validate-per-page-value-list
validate-new-password
validate-item-quantity
equalTo
```

Comment: The link provided redirects you to the website's blog lister page instead of the post itself because [the URL has been updated](http://mageprince.com/blog/how-to-validate-forms-in-magento-2/). Within the blog post itself, it states that you can view the logic in the `validation.js` file, with a link to Magento's file in GitHub, but this shows a 404; [that URL has also been updated](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/lib/web/mage/validation.js).

Comment: @Smithee Thanks for the update. Url is https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/lib/web/mage/validation.js i will update in blog soon.

Comment: @PrincePatel no problem! I didn't realise it was your actual blog post! You're right the URL is that with "develop", I just changed the version number as I know 2.4 is now in development.

Comment: @anonymous I'm not sure if there's a Regex-less method, but this should work: `<item name="pattern" xsi:type="string">^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$</item>`. The pattern says, "match a string where at the start is one or more consecutive digits, optionally followed by a decimal point, to which then between one and two digits must follow afterwards".